# How do I export data from console app to excel spread sheet

Tags: c#, excel, console, export

```
//First start off with a reset state
myDmm.IO.Clear(); //Send a device clear first to stop any measurements in process
myDmm.WriteString("*RST", true); //Reset the device
myDmm.WriteString("*IDN?", true); //Get the IDN string                
string IDN = myDmm.ReadString();
Console.WriteLine(IDN); //report the DMM's identity

//Configure for DCV 100V range, 100uV resolution
myDmm.WriteString("CONF:VOLT:DC 10, 0.1", true);
myDmm.WriteString("Read?", true);
//DmmClass.CheckDMMError(myDmm); //Check if the DMM has any errors

string DCVResult = myDmm.ReadString();
Console.WriteLine("DC Reading = " + DCVResult); //report the DCV reading
```

//I have a loop that continues to read voltage updates every 3 seconds

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, we need a bit more context.

Comment: Your code appears to be communicating with an external device.  What has that got to do with Excel?

Comment: Ok, so right now I am able to view voltage reading using console application using visual studio, like 5.08 volts etc.. But I also want to be able to log this same data into a excel spreadsheet

Comment: I am communicating with a DMM, just want to be able to view voltage readings in console application like its doing now and also export data to excel to log

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am a newbe

Comment: In Visual Studio

Comment: The easiest way is to save a CSV file.  You can create a excel file using oledb methods without using a 3rd party api.

Comment: Is there a way I can just output the console output to an excel row and colum. You know like: Console.WriteLine("DC Reading = " + DCVResult); //report the DCV reading. But using excel code. I guess I need a little more help.

Comment: Maybe I try Jdweng suggestion.

Comment: Does it have to be Excel, because to me it looks like your requirement is basically to 'log' data. And there are tons of logging libraries available, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I need to log it in Excel. Is there code in c# that takes the DCVResult from Console output to a excel spread sheet like the following

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you're looking for a logging functionality, and there are tons of well rounded logging applications/libraries out there that you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Also they will take care of locking etc, since you're constantly writing to a file that's something you need to think about and it will do it for you.

One of my favorites is [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) which you can download as a `Nuget` package. You can find [installation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started) and [basic setup](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics) info on links provided. Remember to install `Serilog` main package as well as `Serilog.Sinks.File` since you want to log to a file.

Here's a really basic example of how to use it, but please read through the documentation and it provides tons of options may come in handy for you. I've created a for loop to simulate your timely data, but the idea remains the same.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File("voltage.log").CreateLogger();

    var line = "IDN = {0}, DCV = {1}";

    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var idn = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        var dcv = rnd.NextDouble();

        Log.Information(string.Format(line, idn, dcv));
    }
}
```

The first line creates an instance of the logger, you only need to do this once. When you call `Log.Information()` it opens up the same file and writes a line, and closes it. This has the added advantage of logging time. Here's a sample output:

> 2019-10-08 10:46:28.697 -07:00 [INF] IDN = 57, DCV = 0.985960515209455
>
> 2019-10-08 10:46:28.717 -07:00 [INF] IDN = 88, DCV = 0.393538948331745
>
> 2019-10-08 10:46:28.717 -07:00 [INF] IDN = 27, DCV = 0.321643328443935
>
> 2019-10-08 10:46:28.717 -07:00 [INF] IDN = 35, DCV = 0.99525734735432

Answer (score 0):

You can write your data easily to an excel file using the ClosedXML Library, here is the link:
https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml